# Python "SpeechRecognition" not working on Mac m1

Tags: python, python-3.x

Ok. so after the troubling installation of PyAudio, [image: PyAudio Still not working]

PyAudio still isn't found! I did pip3 list just to show it's installed[image: pip3 saying it's installed]

What could the issue possibly be?

I am on Mac m1, I tried installing portaudio, I tried reinstalling pyaudio and speech_recognition
This is also my code:

```py
import speech_recognition as sr
#obtain audio from the microphone
r = sr.Recognizer()
with sr.Microphone() as source:
    print("Say something!")
    audio = r.listen(source)
    print(r.recognize_google(audio))
```

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

First, install homebrew on your Mac.

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
```

Copy this code and paste it in your terminal to download and install homebrew and then install PyAudio with homebrew.

```
brew install portaudio
sudo brew link portaudio
pip install pyaudio
```

Run these commands in the terminal and I guess now PyAudio will work.

I had to spend at least 3 days of my project trying to install PyAudio. This method worked for me.

Comment: About that, after I still portaudio, link it (but I can't with sudo, so I remove that), and then I do pip install pyaudio and it still does not work?

Comment: I basically uninstalled portaudio & pyaudio (probably a broken installation anyways), did what you did without sudo because it didn't let me and it still couldn't find the portaudio header file.

Comment: make yourself an administrator or do these steps as an administrator of the Mac, and then Mac will allow you to use sudo and then I guess it should work.

Comment: use pip3 instead of pip

Answer (score 1):

On M1 you need to use the latest portaudio, [see this issue's response](https://github.com/spatialaudio/python-sounddevice/issues/299#issuecomment-752473402).

```sh
brew uninstall portaudio
brew install portaudio --HEAD
cd $(brew --prefix portaudio)

# Links the headers to /usr/local/include
for f in $PWD/include/*.h; do ln -s $f /usr/local/include/${f##*/}; echo ${f##*/}; done

# Links the static libs to /usr/local/lib
for f in $PWD/lib/*.a; do ln -s $f /usr/local/lib/${f##*/}; echo ${f##*/}; done

# Links the dynamic libs to /usr/local/lib
for f in $PWD/lib/*.dylib; do ln -s $f /usr/local/lib/${f##*/}; echo ${f##*/}; done

pip3 install pyaudio
```

And then that just installs correctly!

Tested with PyAudio 0.2.11, portaudio ([eec7bb7](https://github.com/PortAudio/portaudio/commit/eec7bb739771381ab698a6a611d933bdd72cbd8f)), on macOs 11.2.3 with M1 processor.

This approach can be reused to link any library you install with Homebrew btw. It's a common issues with ffmpeg, openssl, and many other libs.